# Better algorithm to calculate this formula

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

Given an array of positive integers `A`, I want to find the following sum `S`:

`S = 2^1 * (S_1) + 2^2 * (S_2) + 2^3 * (S_3) + ... + 2^n * (S_N)`

where `S_i` is sum of product of consecutive `i` integers in `A`, for eg:

`S_3 = (A[0]*A[1]*A[2]) + (A[1]*A[2]*A[3]) + .... + (A[n-3]*A[n-2]*A[n-1])`

---

For calculating any of the `S_i`, I am using method similar to rolling hash, which achieve `O(N)`:

```
Let tmp = A[0]*A[1]*A[2], S_3 = tmp;
For(i = 3 to n) 
    (tmp *= A[i]) /= A[i-3]
    S_3 += tmp
```

And for all two's power I can precompute  beforehand. So now my algorithm to calculate `S` is `O(N^2)`

My question is, is it possible to calculate `S` with a better complexity?

Comment: I don't think you can, since you MUST compute each line separately as there are no arithmetic simplifications you can do. and each line takes O(n) and there are n lines. I am pretty sure O(n^2 is the absolute minimum)

Comment: `(tmp *= A[i]) /= A[i-3]` — isn't this going to fail if `A[i-3] == 0`?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage It's all positive, sorry I missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a recurrence pattern you could use for calculating a solution with a linear time complexity.

Consider an example input:

*A = [2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 8]*

Now look at the partial array with only the first element:

*A<sub>0</sub> = [2]*

Call the outcome for this partial array *R<sub>0</sub>*. It is clear that:

*R<sub>0</sub> = 2⋅A[0] = 2⋅2 = 4*

Then consider the array with one more value from the original array:

*A<sub>1</sub> = [2, 5]*

Call the outcome for this partial array *R<sub>1</sub>*. We calculate that:

*R<sub>1</sub> = 2⋅(A[0]+A[1]) + 4⋅(A[0]⋅A[1]) = 54*

We can try to write this in terms of *R<sub>0</sub>*, hoping we can thus limit the number of calculations to make:

*R<sub>1</sub> = 2⋅(2⋅A[0] + 1)⋅A[1] + R<sub>0</sub>*

Extending again with a third element, we get:

*R<sub>2</sub> = 2⋅(A[0]+A[1]+A[2]) + 4⋅(A[0]⋅A[1] + A[1]⋅A[2]) + 8⋅(A[0]⋅A[1]⋅A[2]) = 360*

Let's try to write this in terms of *R<sub>1</sub>*:

*R<sub>2</sub> = 2⋅(2⋅(2⋅A[0] + 1)⋅A[1] + 1)⋅A[2] + R<sub>1</sub>*

There is a pattern emerging, where the first term looks much like the first term in the previous *R*. It is something like *2⋅(X + 1)⋅A[2]*, where *X* is the first term of the previous *R*. We can generally say:

*R<sub>n</sub> = 2⋅(R<sub>n-1</sub> − R<sub>n-2</sub> + 1)⋅A[n] + R<sub>n-1</sub>*

...where *R<sub>n</sub>* is 0 when *n < 0*.

Now that is something that can be calculated in linear time. Here is an implementation in JavaScript, which also includes a second function that does the calculation in the naive, non-optimised way, so that the result can be compared:

```js
function fastCalcS(a) {
    let r0, r1, r2;
    r1 = r2 = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        r0 = r1;
        r1 = r2;
        r2 = 2*(r1 - r0 + 1)*a[i] + r1;
    }
    return r2;
}

// This function does it the slow way, and executes
// the literal definition of S without optimisation:
function slowCalcS(a) {
    let coeff = 2;
    let s = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        let s_i = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < a.length-i; j++) {
            let prod = 1;
            for (let k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                prod *= a[j+k];
            }
            s_i += prod;
        }
        s += coeff * s_i;
        coeff *= 2;
    }
    return s;
}

var a = [2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 8];
console.log('slow way:', slowCalcS(a));
console.log('fast way:', fastCalcS(a));
```

In languages that provide a `reduce` array method (as JavaScript does), the function can look like this (ES6 syntax):

```js
function fastCalcS(a) {
    return a.reduce( ([r1, r2], v) => [r2, 2*(r2 - r1 + 1)*v + r2], [0, 0] )[1];
}

var a = [2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 8];
console.log(fastCalcS(a));
```

Answer (score 3):

A very similar approach to trincot, but starting at the other end leads to another linear algorithm.

If we had just the array {A[n-1]} then the sum would be:

```
T[n-1] = 2*A[n-1]
```

If we then try { A[n-2], A[n-1]} we get

```
T[n-2] = 2*A[n-2] + 2*A[n-1] + 4*A[n-2]*A[n-1]
       = T[n-1] + 2*A[n-2]*( 1 + 2*A[n-1])
```

Continuing this way we get the recursions

```
T[n-k] = T[n-k+1] + 2*A[n-k]* K[n-k+1]
K[n-k] = 1 + 2*A[n-k]*K[n-k+1]
```

In C

```
int64_t sum( int64_t n, const int64_t* A)
{
int64_t K = 1;
int64_t T = 0;
int64_t i = n;
    while( --i >= 0)
    {   T += 2*K*A[i];
        K = 1 + 2*A[i]*K;
    }
    return T;
}
```

Comment: Well found!! You could save some multiplications by storing `2*K*A[i]` in a temporary variable, and use that in the update of `T` and `K`.